# Better way to use Velocity's GenericTools in a Standalone app?

Tags: velocity

I want to use VelocityTool's GenericTools for some standard formatting in a standalone app. e.g. have something like this in my Velocity template to use the GenericTools' NumberTool formatter:

```
Total: $numberTool.format("#0.00", $totalPnL)
```

How do I associate the above "$numberTool" with the GenericTool NumberTool. Here's my Velocity code:

```
Velocity.init();
VelocityContext velocityContext = new VelocityContext();
Template template = Velocity.getTemplate("example.vm");
velocityContext.put("totalPnL", 100);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
template.merge(velocityContext, sw);
```

Now I know I can do this to get it to work:

```
velocityContext.put("numberTool", new NumberTool());
```

But is that how I need to add all the GenericTools to my app? Manually and one at a time (e.g. another line for DateTool ... etc)? Isn't there a way to make all the GenericTools exposed to my template with out this? I know there's a "tools.xml" that comes with VelocityTools that has the GenericTools defined. Can I just add that to my app to expose all the tools? If so, how?

thanks,
David

Comment: Unless you have a very compelling reason to use the Velocity singleton, it's recommended to use a VelocityEngine instance instead.

Answer (score 4):

http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/ToolManager.html

http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/standalone.html

The default tool configuration provides all the generic tools already.  Though you can create a config if you want to configure those tools.  There's even auto loading for configurations, or manual specification.

```
   ToolManager tm = new ToolManager();
   tm.setVelocityEngine(yourVelocityEngine);
   Context context = tm.createContext();
```

Answer (score 2):

it is at least the way I do it too.
I'll put for example

```
context.put("esc", new EscapeTool());
```

and in the template I simply use then

```
${esc.h}
```

to write a "#" in the code so that Velocity does not parse it as "velocity-script".

I think those helper tools are rather utils and only cover some basic signs. They are not intend to be a standard, you rather can include them on-demand.

I've build for example an abstract class that loads the context of velocity and puts the EscapeTool into the context all the time so that I do not have to add it everywhere.

Good luck with your project

Sebastian